# $f(x)=x^4+x+1$ is separable over $\Bbb F_p$ iff $p=229$

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory, finite-fields, separable-extension

I was asked to prove this in my homework, but when I tried looking at the roots of this polynomial over $\Bbb F_{229}$ I noticed $75$ is a double root of this polynomial and $f=(x-75)^2(x^2+150x+158)$. The factor $(x^2+150x+158)$ is ireducible over $\Bbb F_{229}$ (no root) so over a spliting field it decomposes as $f(x)=(x-75)^2(x-\alpha)(x+\alpha)$ where $\alpha^2+150\alpha +158=0$ is a root of $x^2+150x+158$ in the extension.
How can this be separable over $\Bbb F_{229}$ if it has a double root in the base field?

Comment: I'm sure the exercise is to prove that it is NOT separable. In other words, you solved it. Mind you, $p=229$ is the only prime where this happens. The discriminant of this quartic is $\Delta=229$, and the prime factors of that are the exceptions.